# How can i extract data from excel to website

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xlrd

i am trying to extract data from excel to this website which has `4 textbox` to enter. I have this excel from Column `A` to `D` and about `100rows` containing `data`. How can i enter `A1` to the first `textbox` and `B1` to the second `textbox` and so on? While looping thru all 100rows after i enter submit button.

I've tried to look for resources online but to no avail as mostly is from website to excel.

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/Users/XUPJ21WJH/Desktop/testing.xls")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("test")
rowcount = sheet.nrows
colcount = sheet.ncols
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\XUPJ21WJH\PycharmProjects\Testing\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://cidweb.cat.com/LineDetail.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_name("cwsUID").send_keys("123")
driver.find_element_by_name("cwsPwd").send_keys("123")
driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

for curr_row in range(1, rowcount, 1):
    row_data = []

    obj = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$mainContentHolder$ctlPartControl$cboOrderType"))
    obj.select_by_index(5)
    obj1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$mainContentHolder$ctlPartControl$cboNonOrdPri"))
    obj1.select_by_value("High")
    driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Inside the loop, i would like to enter data from excel to website's `textbox`. Is there anybody that can help me out, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of 4 lists where you append data from each column of the excel file to the corresponding list. So your output should be `list[[data_from_colA],[data_from_colB],[data_from_colC],[data_from_colD]]`

Now you can use the `send_keys` on each textbox and refer to data in the list. For example, `list[0]` for textbox1, `list[1]` for textbox2 and so on.